# nginx rewrite rules /about to index.html?page=about

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I had some htaccess rules for my server and now I am using nginx instead of apache.

I tried to translate those rules and I came up with:

```
location /about { 
  rewrite ^/about\.html$ /index.html?page=about; 
}    
location /archive { 
   rewrite ^/archive\.html$ /index.html?page=archiveindex; 
}
location /sonic1 { 
   rewrite ^/sonic1/index\.html$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=s1;
}
location /sonic2 { 
   rewrite ^/sonic2/index\.html$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=s2; 
}
location /sonic3 { 
   rewrite ^/sonic3/index\.html$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=s3; 
}
```

For some reason these rules do not work

Long story short when someone acceses my website and writes:

`/about` or `/about.html` i want it to be redirected to this page `/index.html?page=about`

These applies to all the other rules, if the about one will work I will figure out how to do the rest of them.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Original apache rules:

```
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ index.html?page=about
RewriteRule ^archive\.html$ index.html?page=archiveindex
RewriteRule ^sonic1/index\.html$ index.html?page=archivegame&game=s1
RewriteRule ^sonic2/index\.html$ index.html?page=archivegame&game=s2
RewriteRule ^sonic3/index\.html$ index.html?page=archivegame&game=s3
RewriteRule ^sonicandknuckles/index\.html$ index.html?page=archivegame&game=sk
```

Comment: thanks for the edit and making them readable

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to show your original .htaccess directives. "`/about` or `/about.html`" - the above would rewrite _only_ `/about.html` - but the required pattern would probably be the same as for .htaccess (if you were using mod_rewrite, or were you using mod_alias)?

Comment: I have added the original apache rules which are working. I have other rules two but I was thinking that if I can figure these out I will be able to do the others

Comment: I have managed to do it by myself. Thanks for the effort anyways!

Comment: Please add it as an answer so we can all benefit :)

Comment: I will, but first i am trying to figure it out why it worked at the beginning and now it doesn't. As soon as I figure it out I will post everything here

Answer (score 0):

As promised, I am publishing the nginx rules that I came up in the end for my previous apache rules (htaccess).

```
location = /about {
    rewrite ^/about$ /index.html?page=about permanent;
}

location = /archive {
    rewrite ^/archive$ /index.html?page=archiveindex permanent;
}

location = /sonic1 {
    rewrite ^/sonic1$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=s1 permanent;
}

location = /sonic2 {
    rewrite ^/sonic2$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=s2 permanent;
}

location = /sonic3 {
    rewrite ^/sonic3$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=s3 permanent;
}

location = /sonicandknuckles {
    rewrite ^/sonicandknuckles$ /index.html?page=archivegame&game=sk permanent;
}
```